# Compare between two weeks of the year sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, select, where-clause

I want to filter values from a table, between two weeks, like this:

select * from SalesWeekly
where SalesWeek BETWEEN '50' and '02'

Problem is, i have no idea how to specify week 50 is from year 2019, 
and week 02 is from year 2020.

Comment: Do you store the `year` in your table?

Comment: Yes, i do store the year in my table

Comment: It would be helpful to see the table structure of SalesWeekly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are storing the year in your table, say in table `SalesYear`, you could concatenate it with the week number and do string comparisons:

```
select * 
from SalesWeekly 
where SalesYear || '-' || SalesWeek BETWEEN '2019-50' and '2020-02'
```

For this to work, `SalesWeek` must be a 2-characters long string, left padded with `0` (so the 1st week should be `'01'`, not `'1'`).